# mongodb crashing on node app while multiple request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, web

in my node app mongoDB throwing an error for a route only some times.

this is my route:

```
app.get("/categories/:catName", async function(req, res) {
    const name = req.params.catName;
    console.log(name);
    var catItem;

    await Category.findOne({ name: name }, function(err, foundItem) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            catItem = foundItem;

        }
    });
    await Product.find({ category: catItem._id }, function(err, foundItems) {
        if (err) { console.log(err) } else {
            res.render("category.ejs", { category: catItem, products: foundItems });
            
        }
    });
});
```

when I start my server and get data from this rouut for the first time everything is working fine.
but when I going back and coming to the same route again I am getting an error as follows;

```
(node:24464) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
    at D:\DEV\WEB\craftyscale\app.js:58:44
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:24464) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:24464) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

what is going wrong here? can someone help me.

Comment: You should not be using `await` with callbacks.  Either use callbacks, or use await (strong recommendation: use await. E.g. `const foundItem = await Category.findOne({ name: name });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your syntax is not correct. In this portion of the code:

```
await Category.findOne({ name: name }, function(err, foundItem) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            catItem = foundItem;

        }
    });
```

You are both treating as a promise, but at the same time providing a callback to the function. If you're using the callback version, you must put your Product.find logic inside of the callback; otherwise use await in the following way (same issue with your call to Product.find, mixing async/await and callback):

```
const catItem = await Category.findOne({ name: name });
const foundItems = await Product.find({ category: catItem._id });
if (err) { console.log(err) } else {
    res.render("category.ejs", { category: catItem, products: foundItems });
            
}
```

You can find more information here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne . You will see that async/await and callback ways are used separately.

Comment: also when i am starting the server it is taking some time to make a connection to MongoDB, in these time if while the server handling requests server which is using some MongoDB model it also throwing an error. currently am waiting until it is connected, but in production, it won't work. so is there any way to fix this? am new to node :)

Comment: Why it doesn't work in production? It depends on what you would like to do. You might initialize and make your server listen until the connection is successful (although during that timeframe, all requests will fail, but there will be no attempts of interacting with the database). But I think you should first check why it takes so long. Also, if you're working with something like K8S or some load balancing technology, old instance should be able to handle existing connections while new instance is up and running.